# Repeated in the table Smarty + Php

Tags: php, html, while-loop, html-table, smarty

I have a problem in in the table

The problem is to repeat I want when it reaches 4 rows to the table is transferred to the new line

Code PHP :

```
    // for : 
$tr = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($post_tv)){ 
    $show[] = $row; 
    if ($tr == 4){
        $tr == 1;
    }
    $tr++;   
    $marsosmarty->assign("show",$show); 
    $marsosmarty->assign("tr",$tr);
}
```

Code Html smarty :

```
<td width="91"><table width="100" height="100" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#666666">
<tbody><tr>
    {section name=table loop=$show}  
    {if $tr eq 3} </tr><tr> {/if} 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <a href="./channel.php?id={$show[table].id}" target="az">
            <img src="{$show[table].a_IMG}" alt="{$show[table].a_DESC}" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="link-img" title="{$show[table].a_TITLE}">
        </a>
    </td>
    {/section} 
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is happening with your current code?

Comment: Problem in that the results are shown in one line I want her to show the ( 4 rows .. ) in table

Comment: Can you try just outputting the value of $tr throughout the loop, just to make sure it does actually meet your $tr eq 3 condition

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are reassigning tr in every iteration, and fetching template it outside while loop, so it makes no sense. You should assign variable after fetching all results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($post_tv)){ 
    $show[] = $row; 
}
$marsosmarty->assign("show", $show);
```

To move to the next row in table, you can use section name and modulo operator like this:

```
<td width="91"><table width="100" height="100" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#666666">
<tbody><tr>
    {section name=table loop=$show}
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <a href="./channel.php?id={$show[table].id}" target="az">
            <img src="{$show[table].a_IMG}" alt="{$show[table].a_DESC}" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="link-img" title="{$show[table].a_TITLE}">
        </a>
    </td>
    {if !$smart.section.table.last && $smart.section.table.iteration % 4 eq 0}
         </tr><tr>
    {/if}
    {/section}
</tr>
```

This way, after displaying 4 cells new table row is created (only if there are more cells, thats ensured by this `!$smart.section.table.last` condition)