# Repeated table Smarty template

Tags: php, html, templates, while-loop, smarty

I have a problem in in the table

The problem is to repeat I want when it reaches 4 rows to the table is transferred to the new line

#### Code PHP :

```
$tr = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($post_tv)){ 
    $show[] = $row; 
    if ($tr == 4){
        $tr == 1;
    }
    $tr++;   
    $marsosmarty->assign("show",$show); 
    $marsosmarty->assign("tr",$tr);
}
```

#### Code Html smarty :

```
    {section name=table loop=$show}  
    {if $tr eq 3} </tr><tr> {/if} 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <a href="./channel.php?id={$show[table].id}" target="az">
            <img src="{$show[table].a_IMG}" alt="{$show[table].a_DESC}" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="link-img" title="{$show[table].a_TITLE}">
        </a>
    </td>
    {/section}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeated in the table Smarty + Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779050/repeated-in-the-table-smarty-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$tr = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($post_tv)){ 
    $show[] = $row; 
    if ($tr == 4){
        $tr = 1; // You have to use '=' instead of '==' 
    }
    $tr++;   
    $marsosmarty->assign("show",$show); 
    $marsosmarty->assign("tr",$tr);
}
```

Remember '==' is to compare variables, it returns TRUE or FALSE. Instead '=' is to set the variable to specific values.

Comment: Not employed, the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

You have to normally populate the array in PHP, don't care about the table in you PHP code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($post_tv)){ 
  $show[] = $row; 
} 
$marsosmarty->assign("show",$show);
```

Then when displaying data, you have to print a `</tr><tr>` every time the current iteration index is a multiple of four (4, 8, 12, ...). You can accomplish this using modulus operator (`mod` in Smarty, `%` in PHP, see **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)**). So, you need something like:

```
{section name=table loop=$show}  
  {if ($smarty.section.table.index mod 4 == 0) && ($smarty.section.table.index != 0)} </tr><tr> {/if} 
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <a href="./channel.php?id={$show[table].id}" target="az">
      <img src="{$show[table].a_IMG}" alt="{$show[table].a_DESC}" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="link-img" title="{$show[table].a_TITLE}">
    </a>
  </td>
{/section}
```

I've used the `$smarty.section.table.index` special variable that tell you the current index of iteration (see **[here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.section.tpl#section.property.index)**). The first condition is needed to search for multiples of four, the second is to avoid printing the end of row at first iteration.

Let me know if it works, I've written code without testing it.